# What seems to be the problems with the arrays in my program? [Java Arrays(exercises)]

Tags: java

**Exercise:**

(Sort students) Write a program that prompts the user to enter the number of students, the students’ names, and their scores, and prints student names in decreasing order of their scores.

What I have done so far:

```
package chapter6;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Chapter6 {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    /*6.17*/    
    //prompt the user to enter the number of students
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the student number ="+" ");
    int number = input.nextInt();

    //array for the names and input
    String[] names = namesInput(number);
    //array for scores and input
    double[] score = scoreInput(number);

    //display students' names in decreasing order according to theri scores
    displayNamesForScores(names,score,number);

}

public static void displayNamesForScores(String[] name,double[] score ,int number)
{   
    for(int i =0;i<number;i++)
        {double temp=0;
         String str ;
         if(score[i+1]>score[i])
         {   temp = score[i];
             score[i]=score[i+1];
             score[i+1]=temp;

             str = name[i];
             name[i]=name[i+1];
             name[i+1]= str;

         }


        }
   System.out.println("Students:");
   for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
       {
         System.out.println(name[i]+" ");
       }

}

public static double[] scoreInput(int number)
{
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
double[] score = new double[number];
 int cnt=1;
for(int i =0;i<score.length;i++)
    {

    System.out.print("Please enter the score for the"+" "+cnt+" "+"student="+" ");
    double scr = input.nextDouble();
    score[i]=scr;
    cnt++;

    }    

return score;
}

public static String[] namesInput(int number)

{
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   String[] name = new String[number];
   int cnt=1;
   for(int i= 0;i<name.length;i++)

        {

        System.out.print("Enter the"+" "+cnt+" "+"name ="+" ");
        String str = input.nextLine();
        name[i]=str;
        cnt++;
        }

 return name;
  }
 }
```

And the error :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at chapter6.Chapter6.displayNamesForScores(Chapter6.java:45)
    at chapter6.Chapter6.main(Chapter6.java:36)
Java Result: 1

I Have been bashing my head for some time , but can not figure it out , why do I get this error.Thank you for your time I am looking forward for an answer.

Comment: I encourage you to learn to use a debugger (Eclipse's is quite good); it will help you easily identify exactly what's causing issues such as these.

Answer (score 4):

You'll get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at this line

```
if(score[i+1]>score[i]) // when i = number -1
```

because when `i = number - 1`, `i + 1` is equal to `number` and that index is not accessible in the array. The maximum accessible index of an array is always `array.length - 1`. Anything beyond that, will throw the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.